# sequential counting with input from more than one variable in r

Tags: r, sequence

I want to create a column with sequential values but it gets its value from input from two other columns in the df. I want the value to sequentially count if either Team changes (between 1 and 2) or Event = x. Any help would be appreciated! See example below:

```
    Team   Event   Value
1    1       a       1
2    1       a       1
3    2       a       2
4    2       x       3
5    2       a       3
6    1       a       4
7    1       x       5
8    1       a       5
9    2       x       6
10   2       a       6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it...

```
df$Value <- cumsum(df$Event=="x" | c(1, diff(df$Team))!=0)
```

It takes the cumulative sum (i.e. of `TRUE` values) of those elements where either `Event=="x"` or the difference in successive values of `Team` is non-zero.  An extra element is added at the start of the `diff` term to keep it the same length as the original.

Comment: That is more complex.  It can be done, but it is probably best to ask as a new question and restore this question so that it makes sense - as it stands your example disagrees with your accepted answer, which is not very helpful to other readers!